# Extract john and 5 from this string and store them in a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string, split

I am new to programming and I have the following string:

```
var username=Owners|cnt1|john,Status|cnt1|8
```

I want extract `'john'` username will change and `8` from this variable, and store it in two separate variables. Can anyone please help out here

Will this below code work?

```
var re = /(test\d+)\-(\d+)/g;

var arr = [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In failed to find `test` in your string. So do matching the word which exists before `,` and the last number.

```js
var username = "Owners|cnt1|john,Status|cnt1|8"
s = username.match(/[^|,]+(?=,)|\d+$/g)
var user = s[0];
var pass  = s[1];
alert(user);
alert(pass)
```

Comment: thanks a lot now how can i store john and 8 in separate variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `split()` method to do this:

```js
var username = "Owners|cnt1|john,Status|cnt1|8";

var words = username.split("|");

var name = words[2].split(",")[0];
var num = words[4];

alert("Name is: " + name + " and number is: " + num);
```

And this is a solution with Regex:

```
var matches = username.match(/(?!\|)(\w+)(?!,)|(?!\|)(\d+)$/g);
var name = matches[0];
var num = matches[1];
console.log("With Regex, Name is: " + name + " and number is: " + num);
```